# Rising memory consumption and rising number of Handlers in PropertyChanged event handler

Tags: maui

I am working on a .NET MAUI App in which I am faced with rising memory consumption. I could create a small sample program in which the situation is shown: [MemoryLeakExample](https://github.com/MAUIoxo/MemoryLeakExample)

When I open the BottomSheet (by clicking on the DotnetBot-Image), select all items by toggling the Switches and just close/open/close/.. the BottomSheet for a couple of times (without changing anything on the selection), I can see my Memory Consumption is rising constantly.

Also, when I open the BottomSheet for the first time Memory Consumption jumps up about 2 MB without any reason for me.

When the App is started and the BottomSheet is just opend/closed/opened/... for a couple of times without selecting a item, Memory Consumption stays the same (well the initial jump is still there, but afterwards it stays the same).

Once items are selected, Memory Consumption rises up constantly, when the BottomSheet is opened/closed for a couple of times.

When I read about Memory Leaks and `WeakEventManager` helping in .NET MAUI, I tried to use them also. But unfortunately, I have a Non-MAUI C# Class Library that is referenced in my .NET MAUI Project.

I went for an alternative implementation that I could use in my Class Library (**MemoryLeakExampleDatabase**) and introduced the `WeakEvent` Class with methods `AddHandler(...)` and `RemoveHandler(...)` to manage them when used with an `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Therefor, I added it to my `StoreSelection`class and used it via `private readonly WeakEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler> _propertyChangedEvent = new WeakEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler>();`:

```cs
event PropertyChangedEventHandler? INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
{
    add => _propertyChangedEvent.AddHandler(value);
    remove => _propertyChangedEvent.RemoveHandler(value);
}
```

There, I could see that `add => _propertyChangedEvent.AddHandler(value);` is called several times, but `remove => _propertyChangedEvent.RemoveHandler(value);` is actually not called at all.

Therefore, I tried at least to delete some handlers that might not be used anymore in the `WeakEvent` class but the added references still grow and grow when I open and close the BottomSheet and look at the growing number of items in `private readonly List<WeakReference<TEventHandler>> _handlers = new List<WeakReference<TEventHandler>>();`.

I do not understand why there is no `remove => _propertyChangedEvent.RemoveHandler(value);` called for the `PropertyChanged` event?

The question for me is also, if this is a Bug in .NET MAUI or whether I am doing something stupid in the `TabView1ViewModel` when I use `Clear()` and `AddRange(...)` on the `ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection> SelectedStoreItems` based on the selected store items. At least this Collection is bound to a CollectionView in the UI in **TabView1.xaml** and is displaying the StoreSelectionItems from **StoreSelectionItemView.xaml***.

At least there might be a registration for notifications that could be updated via `INotifyPropertyChanged` from `StoreSelection`. But, why am they growing and growing?

Comment: What is the minimum amount of code, that can produce this "memory leak"?

Comment: Well, this is kind of hard to tell. First of all, I thought it was opening the BottomSheet. But the increase in Memory Consumption was just when it was opened for the first time (about 2 MB). But, when just closing it without selecting a store and opening it again, did not lead to an increase. So, it must be something afterwards. There, we have just an Update on the ```SelectedStoreItems``` and ```GroupedStoreSelectionItems``` in ```Tab1ViewViewModel``` are bound to the CollectionView in the UI.

Comment: Okay. Before we continue this, I want to say that extra memory consumption is not a proof for memory leak. Can you allocate 1GB of memory, repeating some action?

Comment: I did an output of the Memory Consumption at the Beginning and End of each Method that is in ```Tab1ViewViewModel``` after closing the BottomSheet and could not find the increase in there. Right now, I am just guessing that it is when the UI elements that are just displayed when something was selected via BottomSheet and also that would explain some more elements in the handlers in ```WeakEvent```. But, if so, I do not understand why? The bound ```ObservableRangeCollections``` are just cleared and the selected Elements added again in the ```SelectedStoreItems``` Collection. Is this wrong?

Comment: Or is the View displayed in the BottomSheet causing this in combination with its Selection? Interesting for me is to see the number of handlers increase in WeakEvent over time. The number also drops little in between when I have the breakpoint there, but then still grows. So, to your question - for me it is currently the minimal reproducible example 

Comment: Are you sure you have a memory leak at first place? Do you know the main cause of memory leaks? Trying to fix non-existent memory leaks by reading about them and adding code that creates memory leaks. When you run something, and you have more allocated memory, it doesn't mean you "leaked" it. The memory is not immediately returned to the OS. That would terrible for performance.

Comment: Were you able to allocate something like 1GB of memory, by repeating the same action over and over again or not?

Comment: Well, I detected this problem on my iPhone, when I opened and closed the BottomSheet for about 10 times and the App just closed. I could reproduce the same over and over. When I read about Memory Leaks and about events or delegates for the INotifyPropertyChanged, I came to this assumption. The number of Handlers and Memory Consumption is steadily increasing without changes at the UI which is strange to me. Do you say this is also normal? On the other hand, when the displayed elements by selection are Bound to Tab1ViewViewModel which is Singleton, how would it be released? But also why increas?

Comment: Increase in memory consumption is normal. About handlers, did you write ANY code, that adds a handler, by hand?

Comment: I also called the GC and Memory was not freed which lead to the assumption it is still in use. And why more and more was the question to me. I would not have a problem with increasing Memory, but a closing App after a couple of open/close-steps is not acceptable and I have to look for a „why“

Comment: I did not write Code that adds Handlers by Hand. The Handlers are registered at the ```ProperyChanged-Event``` via ```add => …``` in the ```StoreSelection``` class. But, how would I find out which component is registering them? This class is not newed in this scenario. It is used via DataBinding though in the displayed UI elements. The ```Clear``` and ```AddRange``` could this have an impact?

Comment: @H.A.H. - Any idea how I could catch this bug? In Debug-Build I could not get a crash just on my iPhone when Release is Deployed, but reproducible. In Debug I can see the increase in Memory and Handlers. As I understand the Memory Leak situation it is when Events are not unregistered. When a Store is selected I think there should be a couple of Property Bindings in the appearing UI elements that are bound via DataTemplate of the CollectionView. If no new Store is selected, why would there be more Handlers that’s what I do not understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256500/discussion-between-oxo-and-h-a-h).

Comment: In general, the ```Tab1ViewModel``` needs to be singleton as it provides the main data for different parts in the UI. But, how would the resources of Views be released then when connections via DataBinding still exist to this Singleton? Let’s take the BottomSheet for example, how is this released when it is integrated via XAML in MainPage (Singleton) and displays Data from ```Tab1ViewViewModel``` (Singleton)? I tried deleting the Bindings after closing the BottomSheet, but then I wasn’t able to set it up correctly again as the entire part is connected together via XAML

Comment: @H.A.H. - Discovered that utilizing a loop with `SelectedStoreItems.RemoveAt(i);` to remove all items, rather than using `SelectedStoreItems.Clear();`, maintains consistent handler count and memory consumption after the initial increase in memory. Successfully deployed this version to my iPhone without encountering crashes after using it with this scenario for a while. Planning to conduct further tests with various scenarios, but initial observations indicate improved performance.

Comment: Well, still crashing on my iPhone  don’t know what to do now

Comment: Called `GC.Collect` after closing the `BottomSheet` and Update Database Methods explicitly and no crash so far after 40-50 times open/close

Comment: Amazing. Just the manual call to GC fixed it? Very interesting case. (Maybe having to deal with it, you do not consider it "interesting")

Comment: Not the `GC.Collect()`call alone did the job. I had this before. Replacing `Clear()` with `RemoveAt(i)` for all elements in combination with `GC.Collect()` did it and that was what I tested before. As I did not want to call it manually in my Code, I deleted that call of the GC and deployed to my iPhone. Then it crashed again. When I introduced the `GC.Collect()` call again and deployed, it was stable so far for 40-50 times with open/close without crash