# Using "new ObsersavbleRangeCollection(selectedItems)" leads to crashing App later on

Tags: maui

I don't know where to start, because admittedly, this sounds all weird to me.

First of all, what I wanted to solve was an issue I described in [.NET MAUI Issue #20927](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20927). There, a `DataTrigger` fires, but shouldn't. In this scenario, I have a `DataTrigger` on all `Entrys` which are bound to a Property `IsValid`. The property is updated when one of the other properties `Min` or `Max` are updated. This also leads to an `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid))`:

```cs
public class StoreSelection : ObservableObject
{
    ...

    [Key]                                                   // Primary Key will already be indexed in a Table
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    #region Min Profit

    private int _min = 0;

    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public int Min
    {
        get => _min;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _min, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Max Profit

    private int _max = 0;

    [Column(Order = 7)]
    public int Max
    {
        get => _max;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _max, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    ...     

    [NotMapped]
    [Column(Order = 9)]
    public bool IsValid { get => Max >= Min; }
}
```

What can be seen on **iOS** (only) is the following effect:

[image]

While I was looking for a problem in my Code, I found out that when I use **Option 2** instead of **Option 1**, the scenario was working as expected, but my App crashed after a couple of open/close actions of the `BottomSheet` in my real app:

```cs
private async Task ClearSelectedStoreItems()
{
    int numSelectedStoreItems = SelectedStoreItems.Count;

    for (int i = numSelectedStoreItems - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        SelectedStoreItems.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    SelectedStoreItems.ReplaceRange(new List<StoreSelection>());

    GC.Collect();

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

```cs
private async Task CollectSelectedStoreItems()
{
    // Retrieve the selected StoreItems from GroupedStoreItems and order them based on their SortOrderIndex
    var selectedItems = GroupedStoreItems
        .SelectMany(groupedStoreSelectionItem => groupedStoreSelectionItem)
        .Where(StoreSelectionItem => StoreSelectionItem != null && StoreSelectionItem.IsSelected == true)
        .OrderBy(StoreSelectionItem => StoreSelectionItem.SortOrderIndex == -1 ? int.MaxValue : StoreSelectionItem.SortOrderIndex)
        .ToList();

    // Set IsSelected to true for all selectedStoreItems
    selectedItems.ForEach(item => item.IsSelected = true);

    // Set IsSelected to false and reset Min/Max/OptimalAmount for all items not in selectedStoreItems
    foreach (var groupedItem in GroupedStoreItems.SelectMany(group => group))
    {
        if (!selectedItems.Any(item => item.StoreItem.Id == groupedItem.StoreItem.Id))
        {
            groupedItem.IsSelected = false;
        }
    }

    await UpdateSortOrderIndices(selectedItems);

    MinMaxEntryPairs.Clear();

    await ClearSelectedStoreItems();

    // Option 1:
    //SelectedStoreItems.AddRange(selectedItems);
    
    // Option 2:
    SelectedStoreItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection>();
    SelectedStoreItems.AddRange(selectedItems);
}
```

```cs
public partial class Tab1ViewModel : CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableRangeCollection<GroupedStoreSelectionItemList> groupedStoreItems;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection> selectedStoreItems;

    ... // Includes the methods from above
}
```

**Short explanation to Method `ClearSelectedStoreItems()`**:

This I found out in december when I wrote about [Rising memory consumption and rising number of Handlers in PropertyChanged event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753178/rising-memory-consumption-and-rising-number-of-handlers-in-propertychanged-event?noredirect=1#comment137118430_77753178) which lead to Memory Issues and resulted in this crash. A way out of this was to use this weird Code in `ClearSelectedStoreItems()` to ship around not being able to call `.Clear()`.

In the meantime, I switched my Code and do not use my own `INotifyPropertyChanged` event implementation, but use `ObservableObject` with an `[ObservableProperty]`.

**But now to my question:**

As mentioned above, when I use **Option 2** instead of **Option 1** the unwanted effect with the `DataTrigger` was gone, but my App crashed reproducible after a couple of open/closes of the `BottomSheet` on my **iPhone**, not on Simulator:

```cs
// Option 2:
SelectedStoreItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection>();
SelectedStoreItems.AddRange(selectedItems);
```

```cs
// Option 1:
SelectedStoreItems.AddRange(selectedItems);
```

My question now is, am I doing something stupid here or why does newing the `ObservableRangeCollection` lead to this? What I could imagine is that when I switch over to a new instance of the `ObservableRangeCollection`, I leave open resources from the old one, e.g. really non released unsubscriptions from PropertyChangedEvent notifications or something like that.

I also tried using different options with using `new ObservableRangeCollection()` without an item and then `Add(...)` instead of `AddRange(...)` or `AddRange(..., NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)` etc. it is all the same. When I use the code above no crash, when I change to a new instance of the `ObservableRangeCollection` it crashed afterwards after certain open/closes of the `BottomSheet` without changing anything (like selecting or unselecting items).

Is there anything known about such effects or memory issues when using `ObservableRangeCollection` or when newing it? Or do I have to replace the Binding on the `CollectionView` too everytime when I create a new instance (thought an `[ObservableProperty]` should be all I have to use here)?

In case you need more code an example project can be found on https://github.com/MAUIoxo/DataTriggerCorrupted_20927

Comment: Does this issue only occur on iOS devices? Have you tested on other platforms? And after downloading your demo, I didn't succeed in building your app.

Comment: I could see it only on iOS so far, on https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20927 I also made an animated gif to see the same scenario on Android. I downloaded it to my iPhone and had the same effect. What makes it really worse is that it crashes when I take a `new ObservableRangeCollection<SelectedStoreItem>(...)`. When I had such an effect in December and found out it was gone deleting all the elements by using a combination of `RemoveAt(i)` (not `.Clear()`) with `GC.Collect()`, I found out that in my Models class I only had PropertyChangedEvent subscriptions without unregistration

Comment: Why does this App not build on your machine? It built without errors on mine. Do you have a configuration that allows nightly builds as can be found on .NET MAUI Github project https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Nightly-Builds ?

As written above, I wondered about these EventRegistrations that never got unreleased. Back then, I did not use `ObservableObject` in my model classes and used my own `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Now, I use `ObservableObject` but as far as I know they already use these `WeakEventReferences` to release the subscriptions. In Release it reluctantly crashes, not in Debug

Comment: I also tried with `AddRange(itemsToAdd, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);` which made it worse actually regarding crashes of the App. I also tried with class derived from `ObservableRangeCollection()` and an implementation similar to https://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/ which underneath also uses `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`. I thought this could help using `Reset` here, but it felt like it acutally made it worse. Is there a way I can see all event subscriptions all over my App?

Comment: I am still struggling: when I use `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` it makes it definitively better regarding the unwanted `DataTrigger`-UI effect. **But**, it makes it **absolutely worse** regarding App crashes. Whenever I used the `Reset` in anywhere, be it by making a `new ObservableRangeCollection()` or by use of `AddRange(..., NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)` I got the crashes shortly after when I did this for a couple of times one after another. Why is it like that and how can I find out what it is?? Simulator stays alive, but on iPhone Crashes without any hint - App just gone

Comment: Have you rechecked if you have uploaded all the necessary files of your app? I still can't successfully build the project. You can create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: I just cloned the repository https://github.com/MAUIoxo/DataTriggerCorrupted_20927 into a new folder, deleted all bin/obj folders and did the build starting with project 1) "Maui.Controls.BottomSheet", 2) "DataTriggerCorruptedExampleDatabase" and then 3) "DataTriggerCorruptedExample" which had absolutely no problems. Can you post your error message so I could maybe try to assist?

Comment: And in case you just want to see the "MemoryLeak", I put it together into https://github.com/MAUIoxo/MemoryLeakExample_21015 which shows the rising memory consumption

Comment: Here also the link to the more detailed Bug description: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21015

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT - just wanted to ask if it was possible for you to build?

Comment: Sorry, I still can't compile your latest demo.  And since there is an issue about this and it also has been added to the backlog, please be patient and wait for the update.

Comment: Okay, but I am currently wondering. I would expect that his is compilable and hope this is also possible for somebody that can take care of the issue. So, could you tell what the compile error was?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered multiple issues causing crashes in a release build.
Maybe this can help?
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20981#issuecomment-1985892836